# How can i get the inside of a face selection selected?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, faces

I am trying to create a script that selects the inside of a face selections. does anyone know how to solve this? and i am not talking about pressing "linked" with your mouse, it needs to be done by a script.

[image]

Comment: Theres a similar built in operator called *select boundary loop inner-region*. Perhaps it's source would make for interesting reading

Comment: I see you have couple of questions basically asking people to code something for you. There is nothing wrong with it, there will be people to do it for you for free. But if you make a bigger effort and look at lower-level stuff - like 'How to access vertex dara?', ''How to select/deselect with python' etc. - you will find that you will learn much more. It's all here already answered.

Comment: Jerryno, i will keep that in Mind i actually try to learn some basics some days ago, it's a hard thing with time when you freelance.I am a painted not a programmer so thing's do not some easy on that department. but i will do my best for sure,thanks for the advice.